# Python SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python

My python version is 3.4, below is the error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module    
    from avs_client import AlexaVoiceServiceClient
  File "/home/mstts/Documents/Amazon/alexa-voice-service-client/avs_client/__init__.py", line 1, in <module    
    from avs_client.avs_client.client import AlexaVoiceServiceClient
  File "/home/mstts/Documents/Amazon/alexa-voice-service-client/avs_client/avs_client/client.py", line 5, in <module    
    from avs_client.avs_client import authentication, connection, device, ping
  File "/home/mstts/Documents/Amazon/alexa-voice-service-client/avs_client/avs_client/connection.py", line 64
    **authentication_headers,
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And below is code segment which raises the error.

```
    headers = {
        **authentication_headers,
        'Content-Type': multipart_data.content_type
    }
```

Thanks for anyone who could be as kind to let me know what I am doing wrong and why that would be great!

Comment: Is `authentication_headers` a dictionary? Then, what is wrong with: `headers = {'Content-Type': multipart_data.content_type}` and `headers.update(authentication_headers)`?

Comment: paste your full code

Comment: @Ozgur Vatansever, the change works. But why ** is not work here?

Comment: Because it’s not valid syntax in Python versions prior to 3.5, see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This additional unpacking syntax for dictionary literals was introduced in Python 3.5 (see [PEP-448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)); in earlier versions, it’s a syntax error. If you cannot upgrade, you will have to create the headers in two steps, e.g.:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': multipart_data.content_type}
headers.update(**authentication_headers)
```

as suggested by Ozgur [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378430/python-syntaxerror-invalid-syntax/46379044#comment79715407_46378430).